# Play Audio clip onclick of icon in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNFqa.png][1]

Hi I am trying to make it such that a audio recording would play when my user clicks on the speaker icon in the picture shown above. Would appreciate any help or prompt for me to go towards the correct direction as all I have found on google so far is react native sound players which come with a whole set of play pause and volume buttons which I do not need since the audio clip I have is probably just 2 seconds long which is a simple pronunciation of the number they have selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use any sound player library to do so.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player

You can use this library to play audio either local file or from url

Comment: I have tried the sound player but it seems to keep returning me "cannot play the sound file [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSoundPlayer.playUrl')]" even though I have the file in my folder. 'SoundPlayer.playUrl('./NumberAudio/One.mp3')' I have tried the playSoundFile as well as the playUrl but both returns me the same result.

Comment: are you trying it on iOS? Make sure to run pod install. The error means the library is not properly installed. One more option is this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend managed to make the react native sound player work so now my audio works. Thanks